# Use SVM in PHP running on XAMPP server

Tags: php, xampp, svm

I'm trying to use SVM in my PHP project, I'm using XAMPP as my server, I've tried all the solutions I found,

- I downloaded php_svm.dll and pasted it in xampp/php/ext directory
- I downloaded libsvm.dll and pasted it in xampp/php directory
- I've added extension=php_svm.dll in the php.ini using the run as admin when editing.

I'm still getting this error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SVM' not found in ...

Comment: Did you restart xampp?  Did you check phpinfo() to see if it's loading?  Are you using the right version of SVM (64bit or 32bit)?

Comment: I did, it's working using php 7.3.1, and I've tried the thread safe and non thread safe versions for 64bit both same issue, can you provide me links to the for php_svm.dll and libsvm.dll ?

Comment: What does "it's working using php 7.3.1" mean?  That's the first time you've mentioned the version of PHP you're using.  Are you normally using a different version?  
What link do you need?
https://pecl.php.net/package/svm/0.2.3/windows